List index out of range in Chaquopy
I have an Android app that uses Chaquopy to implement a genetic algorithm in Python. The app passes an array to the Python function 'the_real_GA', the Python function converts it to a list with Location values, which is used for the GA. The list will then be returned, likely as an array.
I keep getting the error com.chaquo.python.PyException: IndexError: list index out of range.
Log:
  Caused by: com.chaquo.python.PyException: IndexError: list index out of range
                                                                                                        at <python>.Chromosome.calculate_distance(Chromosome.py:60)
                                                                                                        at <python>.Chromosome.__init__(Chromosome.py:54)
                                                                                                        at <python>.GeneticAlgorithm.initialize(GeneticAlgorithm.py:16)
                                                                                                        at <python>.main.execute_GA(main.py:18)
                                                                                                        at <python>.main.the_real_GA(main.py:41)
                                                                                                        at <python>.chaquopy_java.call(chaquopy_java.pyx:354)
                                                                                                        at <python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_PyObject_callAttrThrowsNative(chaquopy_java.pyx:326)
                                                                                                        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrowsNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrows(PyObject.java:232)
                                                                                                        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttr(PyObject.java:221)
                                                                                                        at com.example.gotravel01.LoadingScreen.onCreate(LoadingScreen.kt:39)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 


main.py:
import GeneticAlgorithm as GA
import Chromosome as chr


#data = [
#    ["2", "Padang Kota Lama (Esplanade)", "Tourist hotspot", "14240", "4.3", "5.420548751", "100.3443193"],
#    ["5", "Kek Lok Si Temple", "Religious site", "9974", "4.4", "5.399854925", "100.2736609"],
#    ["1", "Penang Little India", "Tourist hotspot", "15127", "4.3", "5.417400799", "100.3393882"],
#    ["4", "Penang Hill", "Nature", "12895", "4.3", "5.409486582", "100.2775463"],
#    ["12", "New World Park", "Food", "5875", "4", "5.420642255", "100.3269356"]
#]

def execute_GA(dataArray, dataset):
    generations = 100
    pop_size = 10
    mut_rate = 0.1

    # Initialize the population
    generated_pop = GA.initialize(dataset, pop_size)

    # Execute the GA for the specified number of generations
    for i in range(generations):
        # Create a new generation
        new_gen = GA.new_generation(generated_pop, mut_rate)

        # Print the best cost for the current generation
        best_cost = GA.find_best(new_gen).cost
        if (best_cost == 0):
            break
        print(f"Generation {i + 1}: Best Cost = {best_cost}")

        # Update the population for the next generation
        generated_pop = new_gen

    # Return the final generation and costs for plotting
    return new_gen

def the_real_GA(dataArray):
    # pass Arrray<Array<String>> to be used in chromosome
    dataset = chr.generate_location_dataset(dataArray)

    final_generation = execute_GA(dataArray, dataset)

    best_solution = GA.find_best(final_generation)

    print(best_solution.chromosome)

    final_location_list = []

    for i in range(len(best_solution.chromosome)):
        # get id from each location and print out its associated name from dataset
        location_id = dataset[i-1].id
        location_name = dataset[location_id-1].name
        final_location_list.append(location_name)

    return final_location_list

Chromosome.py
import random
import math
import csv
from typing import List

class Location:
    def __init__(self, id, name, x_coord, y_coord):
        self.id = int(id)
        self.name = name
        self.x_coord = float(x_coord)
        self.y_coord = float(y_coord)

# extract data from dataset and put in a List with Location values
dataset = []

def generate_location_dataset(dataArray):
    for element in dataArray:
        id, name, x, y = element[0], element[1], element[5], element[6]
        dataset.append(Location(id=id, name=name, x_coord=x, y_coord=y))

    return dataset

# with open('test.csv', 'r') as file:
    # reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    # next(reader)
    # for row in reader:
        # id, name, x, y = row[0], row[2], row[6], row[7]
        # dataset.append(Location(id=id, name=name, x_coord=x, y_coord=y))

# take dataset as parameter and create distance matrix

def generate_dist_matrix(nodes_list):
    node_number = len(nodes_list)
    matrix = [[0 for _ in range(node_number)] for _ in range(node_number)]

    for i in range(node_number):
        for j in range(node_number):
            if i != j:
                x1, y1 = nodes_list[i].x_coord, nodes_list[i].y_coord
                x2, y2 = nodes_list[j].x_coord, nodes_list[j].y_coord
                matrix[i][j] = math.dist((x1, y1), (x2, y2))

    return matrix

dist_matrix = generate_dist_matrix(dataset)

# chromosome class contains name, x, y, distance, and fitness.
# Use distance to calculate fitness.

class Chromosome:
    def __init__(self, nodes_list):
        self.chromosome = nodes_list
        self.ids_in_list = [node.id for node in nodes_list]
        self.cost = self.calculate_distance()
        self.fitness_value = 1 / self.cost if self.cost != 0 else float('inf')

    def calculate_distance(self):
        total_distance = 0
        for i in range(len(self.chromosome) - 1):
            total_distance += dist_matrix[self.chromosome[i].id - 1][self.chromosome[i + 1].id - 1]
        return total_distance

print(dist_matrix)

GeneticAlgorithm.py
import random
import Chromosome as chromo

def create_random_list(node_list):
    start = node_list[0]
    temp = node_list[1:]
    random.shuffle(temp)
    temp.insert(0, start)
    temp.append(start)
    return temp

def initialize(data, pop_size): #generates an initial population
    initial_pop = []
    for _ in range(pop_size):
        temp = create_random_list(data)
        generated_chromosome = chromo.Chromosome(temp)
        initial_pop.append(generated_chromosome)
    return initial_pop

def selection(population): #selects two chromosomes randomly from the population
    ch1 = random.choice(population)
    ch2 = random.choice(population)
    if ch1.fitness_value > ch2.fitness_value:
        winner = ch1
    else:
        winner = ch2

    return winner
    #while ch2 == ch1:
    #    ch2 = random.choice(population)
    #return ch1, ch2

def crossover(chr1, chr2):
    # choose crossover point randomly
    cross_point = random.randint(1, 4)

    crossed_chr1 = chr1.chromosome
    crossed_chr2 = chr2.chromosome

    for i in range(cross_point):
        crossed_chr1[i], crossed_chr2[i] = crossed_chr2[i], crossed_chr1[i]

    return crossed_chr1, crossed_chr2

def mutation(chromosome):
    swap_index1 = random.randint(1, len(chromosome) - 2)  # Avoid swapping start/end nodes
    swap_index2 = random.randint(1, len(chromosome) - 2)
    chromosome[swap_index1], chromosome[swap_index2] = chromosome[swap_index2], chromosome[swap_index1]
    return chromosome

def find_best(generation):
    return min(generation, key=lambda x: x.cost)

def new_generation(previous_gen, mutation_rate):
    new_generation = [find_best(previous_gen)]
    for _ in range(len(previous_gen) // 2):
        parent_1 = selection(previous_gen)
        parent_2 = selection(previous_gen)
        child_1, child_2 = crossover(parent_1, parent_2)
        if random.random() < mutation_rate:
            child_2 = mutation(child_2)
        new_generation.append(chromo.Chromosome(child_1))
        new_generation.append(chromo.Chromosome(child_2))

    return new_generation

LoadingScreen.kt

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import com.chaquo.python.Python
import com.chaquo.python.android.AndroidPlatform
import com.github.doyaaaaaken.kotlincsv.dsl.csvReader


class LoadingScreen: ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //use functions to read CSV, extract locations, sort based on interests and familiarity
        val csvReader = CSVReader()
        var location = getIntent().getStringExtra("City")
        var interests = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("Selected Interests")
        var selectedFamiliarity = getIntent().getStringExtra("Selected Familiarity")

        val input = assets.open("$location.csv")
        val rows: List<List<String>> = csvReader().readAll(input)

        setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen)

        //use functions to sort based on interests and familiarity
        val sortedArray = csvReader.sortDestinations(
            rows,
            interests,
            selectedFamiliarity
        )

        //do genetic algorithm (either here or in another class)
        if (!Python.isStarted()) {
            Python.start(AndroidPlatform(this))
        }
        val py = Python.getInstance()
        val module = py.getModule("main")
        val array = module.callAttr("the_real_GA", sortedArray)
        val listt = module.get("dataset")?.asList()
        Log.d("datalistt", listt.toString())
        //val finalGeneration = array?.toJava(List::class.java)

        //get list returned from GA, send to ItineraryScreen, proceed to next Activity
        val intent = Intent(this, ItineraryScreen::class.java)
    }
}

I used the commented array 'data' in main.py as a placeholder for dataArray to check if passing dataArray was the issue, but the issue still remained.
I tried debugging with Logcat after py.getModule(main), but the dataset value returned was null, which might have been because it wasn't defined yet.
I'd really appreciate help, thank you!

The relevant line in calculate_distance has 4 indexing operations. But the indexing of self.chromosome looks safe because of the range limit, so the problem is probably with dist_matrix, or the values you're using to index into it. Try adding more print statements to get information about what these values are.
